# Cant receive message from Firebase in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I develop a web with notification push like whatssap, I use firebase cloud message for this, i try to send notification from firebase console using token, but I do not get anything in console logs, not even mistakes

This is de firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-messaging.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js');

firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    // Customize notification here
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: 'Background Message body.',
        icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
    };

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

this is the index.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.0/firebase.js"></script>

    <script>
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      // ...
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think messaging works locally. You have to host on HTTPS. I had a similar problem. Then I hosted my app on firebase and everything worked.

Comment: Oh, I need deploy this web in a Cloud Server, so when I do it, then should it work?

Comment: If you use https. That's what fixed it for me.